# what is locking in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

can anyone please help me to understand the concept of locking in sql server?
What i understand is, it prevents others from using the locked data.
What each type of locks do?
what is more about it with examples?

Comment: Just checked ur profile,u have asked 3 questions and you have not selected any of the answers as Accepted answer..its a good practice to select any of the answer as an ACCEPTED answer if you find it useful...

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to learn the locking concepts..that is why u need examples too !!!

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-locking-in-sql-server

you can find all the types of locks according with examples.
its a great article.
Please take a look at it..

Regards

Comment: @agnes, I noticed your edit to this response got rejected. Looking at the edit, it is clear it was meant as a comment. You can use the *add comment* button to ask additional clarification to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

if u want more details related to Sql server locking u can refer

you can find all the types of locks . Please take a look at it..

http://selectinsql.blogspot.in/2012/11/introduction-to-locking-in-sql-server.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you designing an app and looking to maintain ACIDity? If that is the case, I would suggest you start with the **ISOLATION_LEVEL** setting for transactions/sessions. It's a better practice to specify the ISOLATION_LEVEL you need rather than issuing explicit locking behavior using query hints.

**[SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)**

**[Isolation Levels in the Database Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122.aspx)**

If you have a blocking problem you need to diagnose (too much waiting taking place because the same or adjacent data is accessed), then these would be a good place to start...

**[Understanding and resolving SQL Server blocking problems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224453)**

**[Troubleshooting Blocking 101 on SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/MSSQLServerAdmin/troubleshooting-blocking-101-on-sql-serv)**